# different validation politic for inhertiance classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

How to configure different validation politics for so classes:

```
   @MappedSuperClass
    public class Base{
       @Size(min=4)
       String name;
   }
```

and so:

```
public class Child extends Base{
   @NotBlank
   String surname;
}
```

If I create Base class I want switch off validation.
But if I create Child class I want switch on validation.

How can I so?

**UPDATE**

I validate using spring class `BindingResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2638), for example BaseGroup and ChildGroup. Then you can always validate your objects using only ChildGroup, so in a case of base class all checks will be omitted.

**Update.** Example:

```
 @MappedSuperClass
 public class Base{
    @Size(min=4, groups = BaseGroup.class)
    String name;
}

public class Child extends Base{
    @NotBlank(groups = ChildChecks.class)
    String surname;
} 

Base base = new Base();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Base>> baseViolations = validator.validate( base , ChildChecks.class);
// I suppose that this list will always be empty, because no constraints are defined for ChildChecks group in Base class

Child child = new Child();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Child>> childViolations = validator.validate( child,  BaseGroup.class, ChildChecks.class );
// All checks wil be verified here, because we use two groups
```

Comment: @user2674303 I fixed list line in my response